# Encountering error command 'sudo' not found

Tags: sudo

I'm fairly new to ubuntu and have tried to fix this issue by updating it several times and following multiple guides yet it shows me the same thing? not sure what the problem is anymore
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc9F6.png)

Comment: It's not telling you `command 'sudo' not found`, it's telling you `command ' sudo' not found` - the erroneous backslash makes the space character a literal part of the command name

Answer (score 3):

A working command would be:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg --dearmor
```

The [MongoDB help page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) gave you the backslashes at the end of the line. It originally looked like this:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
    sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
    --dearmor
```

The backslashes were there to make bash interpret everything as one line. Since you manually put everything on one line yourself, the backslashes are not required anymore. `curl | \ sudo` is equivalent to `curl | ' sudo'`, and there usually no command installed with a space in its name. The original page meant `curl | \[newline] sudo` which equals `curl | sudo` which is expected.

You also had an extra space, so `- fsSL` should be `-fsSL`. `-fsSL` means `-f -s -S -L`, and those are command line flags. The one dash must come immediately before the letter without a space. Here, all the one-dash flags can be put together to abbreviate them (contrast two-dash flags).

There is a copy button on that MongoDB page. You may find it easier to use it and paste the command into your terminal.